# Copying Row data based on count field Tsql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to copy a row of fields based on the count field Example:

```
 ID  | Row1  | Row2  | Row3  | count
-----------------------------------------------
 1   |  MR   | fred  | Flint |  14
```

So copy ID 1 row an additional 13 times to make 14 records. Then change the count field to 1 for every record copied and change the original row to 1.

Im thinking that the use of CTE and row_number would work? but not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER` like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  A.*,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.ID)
    FROM dbo.YourTable A
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects B
)
SELECT  ID,
        Row1,
        Row2,
        Row3,
        1 [count]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= [count]
AND [ID] = 1;
```

*disclaimer: This assumes that `sys.all_objects` has more rows than the value of `count`

Comment: @SoupOfStars yeah, I left the table aliases when it wasn't needed. Updated my answer

Comment: did you set the ID to =1 ? I could possibly have any id with a count of more than 1

Comment: Yes, because that was your sample data. You can of course remove that condition

Comment: Have done thanks, I just need to some how update the table.